# Corba NamingContextExtStub.resolve will not find an object binding what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, corba

first time asking a question here, apologies if its too stupid or simple.
I'm learning CORBA and i am writing a simple client server app using object and context bindings but i am getting this error when trying to resolve an object binding, can anyone give me any idea what i am doing wrong?:

```
IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0
        at org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFoundHelper.read(Unknown Source)
        at org.omg.CosNaming._NamingContextExtStub.resolve(Unknown Source)
        at MyHelloClient.main(MyHelloClient.java:60)
```

Server code:

```
        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");

        NamingContext rootCtx = NamingContextHelper.narrow(objRef);

        nc[0] = new NameComponent("Alpha", "Context");
        NamingContext alphaCtx = rootCtx.bind_new_context(nc);

        nc[0] = new NameComponent("Delta", "Context");
        NamingContext deltaCtx = alphaCtx.bind_new_context(nc);

        nc[0] = new NameComponent("Iota", "Context");
        NamingContext iotaCtx = deltaCtx.bind_new_context(nc);

        nc[0] = new NameComponent("IServ", "Object");
        deltaCtx.bind(nc, iServ);
```

Client code :

```
        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRefClient = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");
        rootCtx = NamingContextExtHelper.narrow(objRefClient);

        NameComponent nc[] = new NameComponent[2];
        nc[0] = new NameComponent("Delta", "Context");
        nc[1] = new NameComponent("IServ", "Object");

        org.omg.CORBA.Object objRefHello = rootCtx.resolve(nc);
```

Comment: It looks like you've bound the object in the NS as `Alpha.Delta.IServ`, while in the client you're trying to resolve the object as: `Delta.IServ`, which the NS clearly can't find as per the exception that the NS throws.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved it for me, as per earlier reply, you need to specify the Alpha before the Delta and IServ

```
NameComponent nc[] = new NameComponent[3];

nc[0] = new NameComponent("Alpha", "Context");
nc[1] = new NameComponent("Delta", "Context");
nc[2] = new NameComponent("IServ", "Object");
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much, that worked, appreciate your time.